# How to chance picturebox background while creating Qr code with QRCoder

Tags: c#, qr-code

I generate qr with QRCoder, each time I download this qr and put it into the image I put below with photoshop. What I want is to have this image automatically in the background while the Qr is being generated, so that I only have to do one operation.

```cs
private void GenerateQRcode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            QRcodeBox.Image = Image.FromFile(@"D:\ETSY\QR KOLYE\hovercode.jpg");

            QRCoder.QRCodeGenerator QRgen = new QRCoder.QRCodeGenerator();
            var QRdata = QRgen.CreateQrCode(textBox1.Text, QRCoder.QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.H);
            var QRcode = new QRCoder.QRCode(QRdata);

            QRcodeBox.Image = QRcode.GetGraphic(50);
        }

        private void download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            QRcodeBox.Image.Save(@"C:\Users\U97\Desktop\14.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        }
```

[image]
[image]

```cs
private void GenerateQRcode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            QRcodeBox.Image = Image.FromFile(@"D:\ETSY\QR KOLYE\hovercode.jpg");

            QRCoder.QRCodeGenerator QRgen = new QRCoder.QRCodeGenerator();
            var QRdata = QRgen.CreateQrCode(textBox1.Text, QRCoder.QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.H);
            var QRcode = new QRCoder.QRCode(QRdata);

            QRcodeBox.Image = QRcode.GetGraphic(50);
        }

        private void download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            QRcodeBox.Image.Save(@"C:\Users\U97\Desktop\14.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        }
```